# No succeeding emission after catching an exception in Flow/LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm loading some data using Flow which works as expected. The problem is, if an exception is thrown (handled in a `<T> Flow<T>.catch`), the succeeding call to `loadData()` is not received by someChannel.asFlow().onEach { print(it) }`. On the other hand, the emission from the channel is still received by terminal flow operator`collect()`declared in`init` block. Do I miss something in handling the exception?

```
// Fragment
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  viewModel.loadData()
  viewModel.apply {
    someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { data ->
        adapter.refreshData(data)
    })
  }
}
```

```
// ViewModel
private val someChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Long>()

val someLiveData = someChannel.asFlow()
  .onEach { print(it) } // no succeeding emission received
  .flatMapLatest { repo.getData() }
  .onStart { /* set values  */ }
  .onEach { /* set values  */ }
  .catch { t ->
    // this properly catch the exceptions from the repository
    /* set values  */
    _errorMessage.value = t.message
  }
  .asLiveData()

init {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    someChannel.asFlow()
      .collect {
        // This one still works even after catching the exception from `someLiveData` stream
        print(it)
      }
  }
}

fun loadData() {
  someChannel.offer(System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

Comment: `.catch` does not keep the flow going after an exception happens, it just doesn't rethrow the exception further down the flow operation.  You might be looking for `retry`.

Comment: What is in your lambda for the `catch()` operator? `this` in the context of that lambda is a `FlowCollector` -- if you want something from `catch()` to be picked up by the `LiveData`, you should `emit()` it. See [the `catch()` documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html), particularly the last two paragraphs and its code snippet.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yep, that's right. It looks like my question is wrong. The issue is when an exception is thrown for the first `someChannel.offer(someValue)` and catch in `.catch`, the succeeding `someChannel.offer(someValue)` seems not emitting for `someChannel.asFlow().onEach { print(it) }`

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! I'll checking this one out